# client side folder

Tags: jquery

folders and files can be created on the client side by using some script?I wanted to create folders and files on client side.

```
mkdir();
```

like the above which makes folders on the server

Comment: it is not possible to create a folder on client side with javascript or jquery

Comment: This is a horrible (non-existing) idea on the grounds, that, if you could do this, what would stop hackers from making sites that r&*p people's computers and do what they like all "willy nilly" on anyone's machine!

Comment: Step 1. Overwrite the hosts file - all IP addresses no point to my site.  Step 2. ???  Step 3. Profit!

Answer (score 5):

You'd need to make a webservice (in the ASP.NET world) or some other server side page that does the creation of directories on the server, then you can call that service / page with the jQuery ajax method

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Granted it's not the "client" creating folders, it's the server at the client's behest. The effect however would appear to be the same?

Comment: Doesn't the question specify that folders are created on the client computer?

Comment: @SurrealDreams OP specified on client-side. I take from that, that they mean client-side scripting.

Comment: @SurrealDreams Looking again I think you could be right, it could be that he would like it created on the client machine... In which case, you're in to ActiveX controls and getting the users to download them (painful!)

Still, nothing like a well presented question to get a concise answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript and jQuery can't create files and folders on the client - this would be a huge security problem.  Not only could scripts ready all manner of data about you - your credit cards, your documents, and whatever else - they could also create malicious files to do terrible things to your computer.  They have no visibility to the clients file system.  The browser is their sandbox and they are restricted to it.

Answer (score 1):

Erm... no. If they could, every spammer in the world would be reading your computer's folders and drives and files and finding out everything about you and you would be none the wiser.

For obvious security reasons, JavaScript cannot access the filesystem.